# Cant get libraries to compile cloud endpoints python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

```
class Patient(EndpointsModel):
    user = EndpointsUserProperty(required=True, raise_unauthorized=True)
    date_of_birth = EndpointsDateProperty()
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()

    def calculate_age(self):
        today = date.today()
        birthday = self.date_of_birth
        self.age = today.year - birthday.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthday.month , birthday.day))

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        if self.date_of_birth:
            self.calculate_age()

....
api_root = endpoints.api(name='ffsapi', version='vGDL',
                    description='API for whole app')


@api_root.api_class(resource_name="patient")
class PatientApi(remote.Service):

    @Patient.method(
                    request_fields=('name', 'date_of_birth'),
                    name='insert',
                    path='patient',
                    http_method='POST')
    def insert_patient(self,patient):
        if patient.date_of_birth: # TODO find a better way
            if patient.date_of_birth.year <1900:
                raise endpoints.BadRequestException('date <= 1900')
        patient.put()
        return patient

    @Patient.query_method(user_required=True,
                          query_fields=['name'],
                          name='query',
                          path='patient')
    def query_patient(self,query):
        return query
....
application = endpoints.api_server([api_root], restricted=False)
```

This is my file when I run endpointscfg.py it tells me that it is not a ProtoRPC service. I have tried application,api_root,and ffsapi. The code deploys fine works fine just can't get the compiling of libraries to work.

Here is the yaml file if that helps

```
application: ******(im just hiding it)
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.application

# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.application


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
# Needed for endpoints/users_id_token.py.
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, because you're only implementing the API with one class, you should decorate the `PatientApi` class with the `@endpoints.api` decorator instead of calling `endpoints.api()` separately and assigning the result to a variable. Then, you'd create the API server with:

`application = endpoints.api_server([PatientApi], restricted=False)`

Finally, to generate the Open API specification using endpointscfg.py, you'd pass in `main.PatientApi` (assuming your source file is called main.py).